# Sum values in different rows if they match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help regarding an issue that I was not able to solve. I tried to figure it out but without reaching my goal. This is what I have:

In sheet 1 I have estimated active customers for a period of time, where columns are months and rows are departments/states:

***Sheet 1***
[image]

Then, in sheet 2, I'm forecasting sales and need excel to return values from sheet 1 depending on which month we are kicking-off for each department:

***Sheet 2***
[image]

Of course, the kick-off month may vary for each department and values from sheet 1 should accommodate according to the selected month on column B in sheet 2.

And within `C2:I4` I have used this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C$1>=$B2,INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$F$4,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,0),MONTH(C$1)-MONTH($B2)+1),""),"")
```

The formula above actually works great when departments are not repeated in sheet 1 but, what would happen if departments are repeated (as shown in sheet 1) and I have to sum values from the same department and show the result on each cell in sheet 2?

I look forward to your kind help!

Thanks!

Comment: Down-voting due to no apparent research...

Comment: I up-voted because there is obvious own effort.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula, designed for your Sheet2!C2 cell.

```
=IFERROR(SUMIF(INDEX(Rodrigo,,1),$A2,INDEX(Rodrigo,,MONTH(C$1)-MONTH($B2)+1)),"")
```

In order for this formula to work you should declare a named range comprising of your range Sheet1!A2:F4. My formula calls the range `Rodrigo`. If you choose another name please change the name in the formula accordingly.

You can exclude zero results by adding a further IF condition to the formula. I would prefer to do that via cell formatting, like `0;0;;` where the third semi-colon determines that a zero will not be shown. You can also suppress display of zeros for the entire sheet in the worksheet options.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SUMIF` like this:

`=IFERROR(IF(C$1>=$B2,SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,$A2,INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$F$4,0,MONTH(C$1)-MONTH($B2)+1)),""),"")`